# Objective-c UITextView detecting texts

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I am using UITextView on my project. TextView detected texts for Address and Phone number and links.
But some detects is Green color is some detects is underline.
I hope to remove this only underline, No texts.

Please help me,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQIbj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AIJW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the following things in UIStoryboard,I believe this should work

[image]

Comment: If we uncheck all things, UITextView not detecting anything,

Comment: I hope to check all phone number, address, links without underline.